# What is the upper limit on gravitational time dilation?

Tags: relativity

First, please forgive me: I'm not versed enough in mathematics to even approach working this out for myself.

Now, the question: how much "slower" could time pass for a person around a supermassive black hole (such as [S5 0014+81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_0014%2B81#Supermassive_black_hole))? Would this increase indefinitely with the mass of the hole, or is there something about maximum density or whatnot that places a limit on this?

I'd imagine that the increasing volume of a hole would somewhat cancel the effects of increasing mass, but I'm such a layperson that I'm merely speculating at this level of knowledge.

Comment: The short answer is that the upper limit is going do fast, that time stops altogether. This, however, is not reachable in a finite number of steps.

Comment: Also, our best guess is currently that a black hole has no volume, that it is a point-like object. This is, to me, a little ridiculous, so I'm going to have to wait for a better theory.

Comment: But the event horizon gives us some analogy of 'volume', right? (Which seems a little suspicious to me, but anyway.)

Comment: *"our best guess is currently that a black hole has no volume"* - this is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time dilation becomes infinite at the event horizon. That is, an observer watching from far away would see the rate that a clock runs slow to zero as the clock approaches the event horizon. This is not directly related to the mass of the black hole. The mass determines where the event horizon is, but it's the distance relative to the event horizon that determines the time dilation.

For a static black hole the time dilation is given by:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}} \tag{1} $$

where $r_s$ is the event horizon radius and $r$ is the distance from the black hole. For interest, the event horizon radius is given by:

$$ r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2} $$

Anyhow, when you are far from the black hole $r \gg r_s$ so $r_s/r \ll 1$ and the time dilation is small. As $r$ decreases towards $r_s$ the time dilation gets greater until when $r = r_s$ equation (1) gives us:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r_s}} = \sqrt{1 - 1} = 0 $$

so at $r = r_s$ time stops completely.

Comment: I was racing to beat John to it but missed by 3 minutes!

Comment: Okay, so if I'm not mistaken, time dilation as one approaches the event horizon is isomorphic to time dilation as one approaches c?

Comment: @crisis.sheep: They are related, but in a subtle way. I'm not sure I would use the term *isomorphic*.

Comment: PS: Wait, wait. Does this mean that an object arbitrarily close to an event horizon would be older than the universe? Or is the age of the universe a function of its age at every position?

Comment: @crisis.sheep wrote *"time dilation as one approaches the event horizon is isomorphic to time dilation as one approaches c?"* - no, that isn't correct.  Time dilation in SR due to relative motion is symmetric (both observe the other clock to run slow) and the question of "which clock is *actually* running slower" isn't meaningful.  This gravitational time dilation is not symmetric.

Comment: @crisis.sheep: an object close to the event horizon would be **younger** than objects farther away. Time run slower near the horizon not faster.

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh, okay, of course. I'm easily confused =)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Alright, we're getting into realms I'm not sure I can grapple with, but the notion of relativistic symmetry is going to keep my thoughts very busy. Thank you!